# JSON File: Count the Full Number of Words with Python

Tags: python, json, text, nlp

For a current research project, I am planning to measure the relative occurrence of a unique word within a JSON file. Currently, I have an indicator for the number of unique words within the file and their corresponding number of occurrences (e.g. `"technology":"325"`) but am still lacking a method for a full word count.

The code as I am using for a full word count `(total = sum(d[key]))` yields the following notification. I have checked some solutions for similar problems but not found an applicable answer yet. Is there any smart way to get this solved?

```
total = sum(d[key]) - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The corresponding code section looks like this:

```
# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()

# processing:
for row in data:
    line = row['Text Main']
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
    line = line.strip()

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = line.lower()

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

    # Split the line into words
    words = line.split(" ")

    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in words:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if word in d:
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])

    # Count the total number of words
    total = sum(d[key])
    print(total)
```

Comment: `total = sum(d.values())`

Comment: Many thanks - that's what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

You are trying to `sum(iterable, /, start=0)` an integer. This doesn't make sense, because `sum` is meant to be called on an iterable. A brief explanation of an iterable is that it's something that you could use a `for` loop on. For example, a `list`.

You could either modify your `# Print the contents of dictionary` loop in one of the two following ways:

```
# Print the contents of dictionary
total = 0
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])

    # Count the total number of words
    total += d[key]
    print(total)
print("Actual total: ," total)
```

Or, more condensed:

```
# Print the contents of dictionary
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])

# Get the total word count
total = sum(d.values())
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. One last point: for the calculation `d[key] / total` I am once again receiving a notification `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'int'`. I assume that I have to convert d[key] into an integer?

Comment: Interesting. `d[key]` should be an `int` and so should `total`. What happens when you `print(d[key], total)`?

Comment: Found a solution: the last line of the code has to include the iterations and has to be amended as follows: `writer.writerows([key, d[key], d[key] / total] for key in list(d.keys()))`. With this tweak, the code is working well. Thanks again for your support :)

Answer (score 2):

python's built-in sum function takes iterable as argument, but you trying to pass an single number to it. your code is equivalent to

```py
total = sum(1)
```

but sum function need add something iterable to compute sum from. e.g.

```py
sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

if you want to compute total number of words you can try:

```py
sum(d.values())
```

Comment: Many thanks - that's very helpful. One last point: for the calculation `d[key] / total` I am once again receiving a notification `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'int'`. I assume that I have to convert d[key] into an integer?

Answer (score 1):

```
d=dict()
d['A']=1
d['B']=2
d['C']=3
total = sum(d.values())
print total

for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key], float(d[key])/total)

    #Count the total number of words
```

d[key] is a single int
d.values() is a list